# Исправить ошибки, реализовать метод toString()

Tags: java, массивы, методы

Создать интерфейс `IntList` и его реализацию `IntArrayList` по аналогии с 
   `List<Integer>`.

Как реализовать метод `toString()`(он должен вернуть строку с содержимым из `count` элементов)?
   Внутри нужно использовать массив не `List`

```
public class IntArrayList implements IntList {

private int List[] = new int[10];
private int count = 0;


@Override
public void add(int value) {

    for (int i = 0; i < List.length + 1; i++) {

        if (List != null) {

            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(List));
            System.out.println();
            int newSize = List.length * 3 / 2 + 1;
            int List1[] = new int[newSize];
            List1[i] = i;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(List1));
        }
    }
    // newSize = List.length * 3 / 2 + 1;
}

@Override
public void add(int index, int element) {
    int[] List2 = List;
    List2[index] = element;
    for (int i = index; i < List2.length; i++)
        List2[index + 1] = List2[i];
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {

        List[i] = count;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean contains(int value) {
    if (List.equals(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int get(int index) {
    int index1 = List[index];
    return index1;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (List != null) {
        return size() == 0;
    } else {
        return size() == List.length;
    }

}

@Override
public int remove(int index) {
    int[] array = new int[List.length - 1];
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while (i < List.length) {
        if (List[i] == 3) i++;

        array[x] = List[i];
        i++;
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void set(int index, int element) {
    List[index - 1] = element;
}

@Override
public int size() {
count=List.length;
    return count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
String s = List.toString();
    return s;
}

}
```

Comment: для того чтобы понять что исправлять, должна быть ошибка. уточните, что вас не устраивает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю `List` - это у вас массив примитивов `int`. Для примитивов нет метода `toString()`. Вам нужно использовать `Arrays.toString(List)` для преобразования такого массива в строку.

Можно написать метод вручную:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i : List) {
        result.append(i + " ");
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: В задаче сказано его нельзя использовать

Comment: @Fo4Ik добавил метод в ответ